# App store submission : Storyboard showing some warnings

Tags: ios7, app-store, xcode5

I have to upload my app on app store. My storyboard are showing some warnings. I am not able to remove them.

These warning are not making any kind of problem in running in application

Will Apple people submit my app with that warnings?

Below snapshot shows the list of warnings :
[image: Snapshot for warnings]

Comment: I think yes, they accept apps with warnings, but what is the warning you are getting if not a secret ?

Comment: I don't think its a big deal. Cross your fingers and submit :)

Comment: Ok...let me think about it ....thanks for answering

Comment: They won't see the warnings, but, it could be nice to remove them (there a few actions to update all constraints, etc.), because if future, if you continue to develop the app, you may face an undesirable issue. Also, did you try in an 4" and a 3"5 screens? That the biggest issue you could have for your iPhone.storyboard, some button that is out of the screen, misplaced, etc.

Comment: yes..i tried in both iphones screens ..working great..i tested on all devices..no issues in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple accepted my application with these warnings